# Multiple charts with different data using chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts

I have 3 charts on the `HTML` page, I use `class` instead of `id` to avoid repeating code,
I need help to change the data of one of them, I tried several ways but the issue still exists,
This is the code

```js
const charts = document.getElementsByClassName('doughnut-chart')
for (chart of charts) {
  const ctx = chart.getContext('2d');
  const config = {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      datasets: [{
        data: [50, 60, 20, 33],
        backgroundColor: ["#1CCFEC", "#A9EDF8", "#BDECDC", "#00D295"],
        label: 'Energy usage'
      }],
      labels: ["VISA", "AMEX", "MC", "DEBIT"]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      cutoutPercentage: 85,
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      legendCallback: function (chart) {
        // Return the HTML string here.
        console.log(chart.data.datasets);
        const text = [];
        text.push(`<ul class="${chart.id}-legend flex-center-vh flex-space-evenly">`);
        for (let i = 0; i < chart.data.datasets[0].data.length; i++) {
          text.push(`<li class="flex-center-vh"><span class="item-bg" id="legend-${i}-item" style="background-color:${chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[i]}">`);
          text.push(`</span>`);
          if (chart.data.labels[i]) {
            text.push(`<span class="legent-item text-gray fw600 fs10">${chart.data.labels[i]}</span>`);
          }
          text.push(`</li>`);
        }
        text.push(`</ul>`);
        return text.join("");
      },
    }
  };
    const legendContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.doughnut-legend')
  legendContainer.forEach(function (thisLegend) {
    thisLegend.innerHTML = window.chartInstance.generateLegend();
  })
  var chartInstance = new Chart(ctx, config);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart-container">
                <canvas id="chart1" class="doughnut-chart"></canvas>   
                <div class="doughnut-legend"></div>            
              </div>
              <div class="chart-container">
                <canvas id="chart2" class="doughnut-chart"></canvas>  
                <div class="doughnut-legend"></div>         
              </div>
              <div class="chart-container">
                <canvas id="chart3" class="doughnut-chart"></canvas>  
                <div class="doughnut-legend"></div>         
              </div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to change the data when first displaying them or after they are displayed?

Comment: If after, why aren't you storing the chart instance `chartInstance = new Chart(ctx, config);` in an array that exists outside of the loop?  The chart instance is your reference to that individual chart.

Comment: @KScandrett when the first displaying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `window.chartInstance` is not set and moreover, my understanding of the logic is to expect three different instances in order to call `generateLegend()` for each of them.

**UPDATED** to show how to change the data of one of the charts:
Moved `legendContainer` outside of the `charts` loop ; Now using an array of chart instance as suggested by K Scandrett.

Here is a proposal (excerpt). Mind the instanciation of the charts inside the primary loop and the generation of the legends outside of the primary loop.

```
let allCharts = [];

const charts = document.getElementsByClassName("doughnut-chart");
for (chart of charts) {
  const ctx = chart.getContext("2d");
  const config = {
    // ...
  };

  var chartInstance = new Chart(ctx, config);
  allCharts.push(chartInstance);
}

let legendContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".doughnut-legend");
legendContainer.forEach(function (thisLegend, i) {
  thisLegend.innerHTML = allCharts[i].generateLegend();
});

// update data
const chartToModify = allCharts[1]
chartToModify.data.datasets[0].data.pop();
chartToModify.data.datasets[0].data.pop();
chartToModify.data.labels.pop();
chartToModify.data.labels.pop();
chartToModify.update();

// update legends
legendContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".doughnut-legend");
legendContainer.forEach(function (thisLegend, i) {
  thisLegend.innerHTML = allCharts[i].generateLegend();
});
```

Changing the data of one of the charts is documented at https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.3.2/developers/updates.html. Mind the call to `update()`.

Complete code here https://codepen.io/beezital/pen/yLzRqXz

Comment: Can you please, change the data of one of them from 4 to 2?

Comment: @Kareem Sultan I have updated the code to show how to change the data of the second chart. This example is based on your code style and algorithm so to minimise the effort to understand the changes. I have not considered providing a well designed solution.